# How to add authentication on Solr 4.3

Tags: solr, solr4

We are using Solr version 4.3. We need to add authentication on this version. We are using it as standalone instance. I tried in version 6.2 and I am able to do in that version using Security.json.

Comment: I think that option is not available in 4.3

Comment: You'll have to use a separate httpd as a reverse proxy in front of Solr and add authentication there. The usual suspects supports doing this (nginx, Apache, etc.).